# Sorting API data from (poke) API with vanilla js with user input

Tags: javascript, html, api, sorting, input

Hey everyone couldnt find this and was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction?
This is for an assignment i'm doing I have to use an API and display the data. I also have to have sorting.

I am using the poke api because its free. I am able to display the data no problem and want to add sorting by a drop or search bar. Not sure which is best. for example by 'type' like grass or water or fire or whatever.

I apologize I'm still pretty new to js.

I have tried:

```
const grass = pokemon.filter(pokemon => pokemon.type === 'grass') 
if(pokemon.type === 'grass'){
return true;
}
```

but I keep getting 400 errors from the api when I do that. Here is my full script:

```
const pokedex = document.getElementById('pokedex');

const fetchPokemon = () => {
    const promises = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {
        const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
        promises.push(fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()));
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
        const pokemon = results.map((result) => ({
            name: result.name,
            image: result.sprites['front_default'],
            type: result.types.map((type) => type.type.name).join(', '),
            id: result.id
        }));
        displayPokemon(pokemon);
    });
};

const displayPokemon = (pokemon) => {
    console.log(pokemon);
    const pokemonHTMLString = pokemon
        .map(
            (pokeman) => `
        <li class="card">
            <img class="card-image" src="${pokeman.image}"/>
            <h2 class="card-title">${pokeman.id}. ${pokeman.name}</h2>
            <p class="card-subtitle">Type: ${pokeman.type}</p>
        </li>
    `
        )
        .join('');
    pokedex.innerHTML = pokemonHTMLString;
};
fetchPokemon();
//Sorting//

// const grass = pokemon.filter(pokemon => pokemon.type === 'grass') 
//  if(pokemon.type === 'grass'){
//  return true;
//  }
// console.table(grass)
```

Not sure if you need it but here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Quick's Pokedex</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/animate.css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <img src="/assets/img/two.png" alt="Pokemon Logo" height="500" class="animated fadeInLeftBig logo" id="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="container">

            <audio class="audio-player" loop src="/assets/audio/pokemon.mp3" controls>
                Error: your web browser does not support this audio player.
                </audio>
            <h1 class="quicks-h1">Quick's Pokedex</h1>
            <ul id="pokedex"></ul>
        </div>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you do not get 400 error because you preform an action on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `sort()` function. for sort by type use `.sort((a, b) => a.type > b.type ? 1 : -1)`

example:

```js
  const fetchPokemon = () => {
        const promises = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {
            const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
            promises.push(fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()));
        }
        Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
            const pokemon = results.map((result) => ({
                name: result.name,
                image: result.sprites['front_default'],
                type: result.types.map((type) => type.type.name).join(', '),
                id: result.id
            })).sort((a, b) => a.type > b.type ? 1 : -1);
            displayPokemon(pokemon);
        });
    };
    const displayPokemon = (pokemon) => {
        const pokemonHTMLString = pokemon
            .map(
                (pokeman) => `
        <li class="card">
            <img class="card-image" src="${pokeman.image}"/>
            <h2 class="card-title">${pokeman.id}. ${pokeman.name}</h2>
            <p class="card-subtitle">Type: ${pokeman.type}</p>
        </li>
    `
            )
            .join('');
        pokedex.innerHTML = pokemonHTMLString;
    };
    fetchPokemon();
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="quicks-h1">Quick's Pokedex</h1>
    <ul id="pokedex"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So if i wanted to sort the data coming in with input from the user how would I do that? I've been able to get the api to pull and display data but as soon as i try and sort it I get errors.

Comment: For example by 'type' in the example above.

Comment: just add `.sort((a, b) => a.type > b.type ? 1 : -1)` to the `map()`. I have updated the snipped